# Derivatives of probability distributions w.r.t. parameters in R?

Tags: r, probability, distribution, derivative

I need the (analytical) derivatives of the PDFs/log PDFs/CDFs of the most common probability distributions w.r.t. to their parameters in R. Is there any way to use these functions?

The [gamlss.dist package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gamlss.dist) provides the derivatives of the log PDFs of many probability distribution ([code for the normal distribution](https://github.com/cran/gamlss.dist/blob/master/R/NO.r)). Is there anything similar for PDFs/CDFs?

**Edit**: Admittedly, the derivatives of the PDFs can be obtained from the derivatives of the log PDFs by a simple application of the chain rule, but I don't think a similar thing is possible for the CDFs...

Comment: The PDF _is_ the derivative of the CDF.

Comment: Yes, but not w.r.t. the distribution parameters, e.g., I am looking for the derivatives w.r.t. mu and sigma in the case of the normal distribution.

Comment: If you're writing software (maximum likelihood or something) so you only need to calculate the derivatives once, one approach is to construct the derivatives using a computer algebra system, print out the derivatives, and then paste the generated code into another program (R, Python, etc). I like Maxima (https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima) but you can also try Sympy (http://sympy.org). It might also be possible in R, but I don't know. Let me know if you want to go down this road and we can talk about more details.

Comment: @RobertDodier, thank you for your comment! I am indeed implementing a statistical test that relies on these derivatives, so calculating their analytical expression once is fine. I'd be happy to learn how to do so with Maxima. Does Maxima have built-in support for common probability distributions?

Answer (score 1):

OP mentioned that calculating the derivatives once is OK, so I'll talk about that. I use Maxima but the same thing could be done with Sympy or other computer algebra systems, and it might even be possible in R; I didn't investigate.

In Maxima, probability distributions are in the `distrib` add-on package which you load via `load(distrib)`. You can find documentation for all the cdf functions by entering `?? cdf_` at the interactive input prompt.

Maxima applies partial evaluation to functions -- if some variables don't have defined values, that's OK, the result has those variables undefined in it. So you can say `diff(cdf_foo(x, a, b), a)` to get a derivative wrt `a` for example, with free variables `x`, `a`, and `b`.

You can generate code via `grind`, which produces output suitable for Maxima, but other languages will understand the expressions.

There are several ways to do this stuff. Here's just a first attempt.

```
(%i1) load (distrib) $
(%i2) fundef (cdf_weibull);
(%o2) cdf_weibull(x, a, b) := if maybe((a > 0) and (b > 0)) = false
 then error("cdf_weibull: parameters a and b must be greater than 0")
                  x a
 else (1 - exp(- (-) )) unit_step(x)
                  b
(%i3) assume (a > 0, b > 0);
(%o3)                           [a > 0, b > 0]
(%i4) diff (cdf_weibull (x, a, b), a);
                        a
                       x
                     - --
                        a                       a    a
                       b                log(b) x    x  log(x)
(%o4)            - %e     unit_step(x) (--------- - ---------)
                                            a           a
                                           b           b
(%i5) grind (%);
-%e^-(x^a/b^a)*unit_step(x)*((log(b)*x^a)/b^a-(x^a*log(x))/b^a)$
(%o5)                                done
(%i6) diff (cdf_weibull (x, a, b), b);
                                            a
                                           x
                                         - --
                                            a
                          (- a) - 1  a     b
(%o6)                - a b          x  %e     unit_step(x)
(%i7) grind (%);
-a*b^((-a)-1)*x^a*%e^-(x^a/b^a)*unit_step(x)$
(%o7)                                done
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This is not as simple as I hoped it to be, because I need to transfer the results from Maxima to R, but it is a good starting point. One more question: Can Maxima express the derivatives in terms of the original function, e.g., make the expressions shorter whenever possible by using the definition of cdf_weibull?

Comment: About expressing derivatives in terms of the original function, there isn't a built-in way to do that, but it seems like it should be possible. Let me think about that.

Comment: That would be great, e.g., for the normal distribution, the derivative of the CDF w.r.t. mu is the PDF * (-1).